# Single shares mixed up with ETFs?

Tags: etf, shares, deposits

I have an account where I am buying monthly a MSCI World ETF. I am now thinking about adding to this account single shares from a few different companies. What impact could this have if I mix up my depot with ETF's and Shares? Or is there no effect at all?

Comment: what sort of impact are you anticipating? What is the deposit you are  asking about?

Comment: My question was just generally asked. Does it make sense to mix up an ETF-deposit with single shares? Or should you just seperate ETFs from single shares?

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  What is a deposit? is it a bank account, or an account at an investment company?

Comment: Oh sorry I think I just translated it wrong. It is an account at a bank just used for investing in shares / ETFs

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting single shares? Get invited to stockholder meetings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is an *investment* account, with ETF in it.

(In America, at least, retail and commercial banks can't offer investments, though they do "partner" or merge with investment banks that do offer this service, so that you can see both checking and savings accounts and investment accounts in one place.)

As for the heart of your question, "*What impact could this have if I mix up my depot with ETF's and Shares? Or is there no effect at all?*" the technical answer is: no effect at all.

Note, though, that while ETFs and mutual funds are "designed" for buy and hold, many people tend to get "happy feet" with individual stocks, selling and buying at the wrong times.

So... first "know yourself"!

Happy investing!

Comment: Given the OP's (minor) translation issue, do you really want to use the phrase "happy feet"? +1 still, nice answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.. I'll think about it.